# javascript regex how to extract url substring

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract "stringtoextract" below I can't see why it doesn't work:
https://jsfiddle.net/dwbnj6z7/

```
  let url = 'https://mystuff.com/test/varstring/stringtoextract?id=test3'
  let regex = /https:\/\/stuff.com\/test\/varstring\/.+\/(.+)?.+/
  var match = regex.exec(url);
  alert(match[1]);
```

Comment: Use `let regex = /https:\/\/mydomain\.com\/test\/varstring\/([^?\/]+)/`

Comment: Better, use `const segments = new URL(url).pathname.split('/');
console.log(segments.pop());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this code. I've changed the regex a bit:

```js
let url = 'https://example.com/test/varstring/stringtoextract?id=test3'
let regex = /https:\/\/example\.com\/test\/varstring\/(.+)\?.+/
var match = regex.exec(url);
console.log(match[1]);
```